# How to add identifier to table row submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

I am currently trying to build a booking system for a theatre. I have 5 different productions which are found from my database with a query in php.

I have a table showing the productions and their associated ticket price. Each row states the production, ticket price and a submit button (using $_POST) to choose that production.

I am trying to send the title of the selected production as production_'production title'. e.g. if hamlet was selected I would retrieve the selection using $_POST['production_hamlet'].

However I do not know how to replace the title of each production found in the query when retrieving the POST.

e.g. on the next page when echoing out to see if it's submitted I don't know what to write after echo $*POST['production*.....'].

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="choose_performance.php">
    <table name="choose_performance">
    <thead id="td">
        <tr>
            <td>Production</td>
            <td>Basic Ticket Price</td>
            <td>Select</td>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $production_set = find_productions();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($production_set)){?>
            <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Title']?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo "production_".$row['Title']?>" value="<?php echo $row['Title']?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['BasicTicketPrice'];?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo "price_".$row['Title']?>" value="<?php echo $row['BasicTicketPrice']?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"
                onclick='alert("Thank you for your selection. Please choose your preferred performance time and date on the next page.");'>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </form>
```

Any advice on how to retrieve the POST would be amazing.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting name="production" only? If only one production can be selected on submit then name can be the same.

Comment: Otherwise just post the production ID and echo it's associated name on the next page?

Comment: I originally used name="production" but then the production at the bottom of my table would always get submitted regardless of which button was submitted.

Comment: How would I echo the associated name from the id?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted...I failed to notice that the form tag was outside the while loop, hence my comment. And I really wanted those 25 points :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `<form>` tag inside your `while` loop so that each row has its own form for submission. This way, when the form is submitted, you only have 2 posted params (production & price). See below:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row[ 'Title']?>

    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row[ 'BasicTicketPrice'];?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="choose_performance.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="production" value="<?php echo $row['Title'] ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['BasicTicketPrice'] ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick='alert("Thank you for your selection. Please choose your preferred performance time and date on the next page.");'>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: oh my god i tried to sort this out this morning for over 5 hours.

Comment: you are such a hero i love you x